# required error in magento2?

Tags: magento2, requirejs

in magento2 add custom.js file

file custom.js

```
require(
     [ 
       'Mageaddons_Popup/js/angular.min',
       'Mageaddons_Popup/js/textAngular-rangy.min',
       'Mageaddons_Popup/js/textAngular-sanitize.min',
       'Mageaddons_Popup/js/textAngular.min'
     ],
     function($){
      'use strict';
    // code 
 });
```

i get error

> Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (a){ "use
>   strict";
>   window.rangy=a("rangy"),window.rangy.saveSelection=a("rangy/lib/rangy-selectionsaverestore")}
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
>
> var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' +
>   id); in require.js

Comment: @ xanka Did something wrong at textAngular-rangy.min. refer for more info http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html

Comment: i get file in https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/blob/master/dist/textAngular-rangy.min.js and not change anything.

Comment: @ xanka Try to define your Library inside "define(["jquery"], function($){"  // your lib code "});

Comment: i tried it, not success. I thing don't nead jquery. u can see https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular